Bessel function of first and second kind as solution of an integral
Needing to solve this definite integral $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}\exp\left[{-\frac{(t-u)^2}{2}} \right] du$$ where $t$ is real, someone make me notice that, although it seems that there is no solution, Mathematica gives a solution when the conditions $t<0$ and $t>0$ are added:
Integrate[1/Sqrt[u] Exp[-((t - u)^2/2)], {u, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> t < 0]

with solution $$\frac{e^{-\frac{t^2}{4}} \sqrt{-t} K_{\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{t^2}{4}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}$$ where $K$ is the modified Bessel function of second kind, and
Integrate[ 1/Sqrt[\[Tau]] Exp[-((t - \[Tau])^2/2)], {\[Tau], 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> t > 0]

with solution $$\frac{1}{2} \pi  e^{-\frac{t^2}{4}} \sqrt{t} \left[I_{\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{t^2}{4}\right)+I_{-\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{t^2}{4}\right)\right]$$ where $I$ is the modified Bessel function of first kind. I tried a lot, but I was not able to derive these results, could someone give me any clue? Many thanks.

The following entry from Erdelyi's table of integral transforms (volume 1, page 146, eq. (23)) seems related: $$\int_0^\infty e^{-pt}t^{-1/2}e^{-t^2/(4\alpha)}~dt=p^{1/2}\alpha^{1/2}e^{\alpha p^2/2}K_{1/4}(\alpha p^2/2)$$ valid for $\alpha$ with positive real part.

This is not a completely satisfactory answer, since there's two summations S1, S2 which I have to hand off to Mathematica still.
First, we rewrite the integral as
$$I(t)=e^{-t^2/2}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{t u}\frac{e^{-u^2/2}}{\sqrt{u}} du$$
and expand $e^{-tu}$ in powers of $u$ to obtain
$$I(t)=e^{-t^2/2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!}\int_{0}^{\infty} u^k\frac{e^{-u^2/2}}{\sqrt{u}} du$$
Under the substitution $x=u^2/2$, these integrals become
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} (2x)^{(k-3/2)/2}e^{-x}~dx=2^{k/2-3/4}\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\right)$$ using the integral definition of the Gamma function. Hence
$$I(t)
=e^{-t^2/2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!}2^{k/2-3/4}\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\right)$$
which we can divide into even and odd parts. According to Mathematica, these can be separately resummed:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^{2k}}{(2k)!}2^{k-3/4}\Gamma\left(k+\frac{1}{4}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}e^{t^2/4}(t^2)^{1/4}I_{-1/4}(t^2/4),\tag{S1}$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}2^{k-1/4}\Gamma\left(k+\frac{3}{4}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}e^{t^2/4}\frac{t}{(t^2)^{1/4}}I_{1/4}(t^2/4)\tag{S2}$$
For reference, the series definition of $I_\nu(z)$ is
$$I_\nu(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(z/2)^{2k+\nu}}{k!~ \Gamma(k+\nu+1)}$$
This is clearly similar to the claimed sums but it isn't evident to me how to verify them. (Note the role played by $e^{t^2/4}$ in each, as well as the Gamma function being in the numerator vs denominator. The latter suggests some kind of reflection-formula business.)
Regardless, for real $t$ we have $t=|t|\operatorname{sgn}{t}$ and $(t^2)^{1/4}=|t|^{1/2}$ so combining these sums yields
$$I(t)=\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-t^2/4}\sqrt{|t|} \Big[I_{-1/4}(t^2/4)+(\operatorname{sgn}{t})I_{1/4}(t^2/4)\Big]$$
For $t>0$ we recover the Mathematica result. For $t<0$, we have
$$I(t<0)=\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-t^2/4}\sqrt{-t} \Big[I_{-1/4}(t^2/4)+-I_{1/4}(t^2/4)\Big]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{-t^2/4}\sqrt{-t} ~K_{1/4}(t^2/4)$$
using the identity/definition $K_\nu(z)=\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{I_{-\nu}(z)-I_\nu(z)}{\sin(\nu z)}$.

For the last formula you want to say "For $t<0$, we have".

@Gary Fixed, thanks

@Semiclassical, excuse me, is there a mistake in the series definition of $I_{\nu}$? There should be $n$ instead of $k$, and $(z/2)^{2n+\nu}$?

Fixed, thanks @umby
